# Save K8S audit logs in s3 bucket

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-eks, amazon-kinesis-firehose

i would like to save K8S audit logs which are being saved in cloudWatch in S3 bucket.
i use kinesis stream and then kinesis firehose in order to save it s3 bucket.
it created a "folder" in the s3 bucket with the relevant logs
[image: S3 bucket]

when trying to get the logs value its show object URL which display unreadable text.
how can i read/get the log info?
is it the best way to send K8S audit logs to S3?

[image]

Comment: you cab download it or `aws s3` cli or `s3api` to copy them to local

Comment: The url looks ok. The "unreadable text" is simply url encoding   https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP. 

The way you upload sounds fine, how are you trying to download it? please share some code.